# Render Value Only After Error Handling and Fetch is complete

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React JS and still struggling in mastering a few concepts.

I am trying to do error handling for my code and only display the API response only after the Fetch is complete.

Below I have my code which is what I have done.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Transaction({ response }) {
  const [transaction, setTransaction] = useState([]);
  const token = "2c506c6b-d880-36bb-bdba-a035d1464b35";

  const requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://api.flash-internal.flash-group.com/ecommerceManagement/1.0.0/api/transaction/5KISDW53",
      requestOptions
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setTransaction(data));
  }, []);

//   console.log(transaction.result.details[0].vouchers[0].result);

  return (
    <>
        <div>
            Hello
            <b>Transaction Status:</b> {transaction.status} <br />
        </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Transaction;
```

And below is how I am trying to do some clean error handling. Can someone help me, or at least refer me to where I can learn how to do this properly.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Transaction({ response }) {
  const [transaction, setTransaction] = useState([]);
  const token = "2c506c6b-d880-36bb-bdba-a035d1464b35";

  const requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };

  function handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://api.flash-internal.flash-group.com/ecommerceManagement/1.0.0/api/transaction/5KISDW53",
      requestOptions
    )
      .then(handleErrors)
      .then((response) => console.log("ok"))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error))
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setTransaction(data));
  }, []);

  //   console.log(transaction.result.details[0].vouchers[0].result);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <b>Transaction Status:</b> {transaction.status} <br />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Transaction;
```

Comment: Is the `transaction` state an array, like declared, or an object, like accessed when rendered? It's unclear what any issue is other than a type mismatch in the state. It's impossible to display/render the response before the code has received it. If you only want to render fetched content ***after*** all fetching logic has completed then use a loading state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An issue I see is that you are implicitly returning the void result of a console log in the Promise chain, so later thenables aren't receiving the unpacked JSON response value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(
    "......",
    requestOptions
  )
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then((response) => console.log("ok")) // <-- returns undefined!
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    .then((response) => response.json()) // <-- can't call `json()` of undefined!
    .then((data) => setTransaction(data));
}, []);
```

It seems like you are asking about the fetch processing. I would suggest checking for the ok response before returning the `json`, right there inline. If you want to conditionally wait to display any fetched content then use a loading state.

Example:

```
function Transaction({ response }) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [transaction, setTransaction] = useState();

  const requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetch(
      ".....",
      requestOptions
    )
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw Error(response.statusText);
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setTransaction(data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return null; // or loading spinner/etc
  }

  return (
    <>
      {transaction
        ? (
          <div>
            <b>Transaction Status:</b> {transaction.status} <br />
          </div>
        )
        : <div>No transaction data</div>
      }
    </>
  );
}
```

If you want to display any errors then add some error state and some conditional rendering logic to display it, similar to the `transaction state`.

Comment: This completely works. But what if I want to Display the voucher details?  If you run the GET in Postman you will see the result and structure. Thank you, Drew, you have been so helpful to me these past few weeks. I wish I had your LinkedIn, youtube or Twitter handle. I would love to endorse your work.

Comment: @ManassehCodes Can you clarify what the "voucher details" are that you want to display? Is this the `transaction` state that is being rendered?

Comment: This is how I am currently displaying 
    console.log(transaction.result.details[0].vouchers[0].result.referenceId);

Comment: @ManassehCodes Since the response value appears to contain arrays are you asking how to dynamically render the response/result? Or something else?

Comment: Yes Drew. That is what I am asking.

Comment: @ManassehCodes Normally you'd map the parts of the response/result that are arrays. *Sometimes*, however, an API returns data in an array of length 1 (*for some reason ‍♂️*). Can you confirm the expected API response shape for us? Do you expect there to be multiple details and vouchers that need to be rendered?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) in react.

```
return (
    {
      transaction.length === 0 ? <></> :
        <>
          <div>
            <b>Transaction Status:</b> {transaction.status} <br />
          </div>
        </>

    }
)
```

you can use loading or anything that you want instead of `<></>` and also any other proper condition for data existence.